# Fast query slows with join to small table

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, sql-server-2016

I have a query that's quite fast (consistently less than 2 seconds) until I
include the event_meals as join in the final `SELECT`. Then, the query takes
more than 6 minutes. Additionally, the query goes from unnoticed to
overburdening the database; agents aren't able to perform any tasks until I
cancel the query.

```sql
WITH event_meals (m2m_event_id, m2m_meal_id, m2m_meal_name, m2m_meal_description, choice_required) AS (
    -- Here we find those multi-to-multi relationships involving meals (supplier ID 16)
    SELECT
        m2mDesignation_EventProductId, m2mDesignation_AddOnProductId, AddOnDetail.Subtitle, AddOnDetail.ShortDescription, CASE [AddOnChoiceEnumId]
                WHEN 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
    FROM AddOn
        JOIN product ON AddOn.m2mDesignation_AddOnProductId = product.productid
        JOIN AddOnDetail ON AddOn.AddOnDetailId = AddOnDetail.AddOnDetailId
    WHERE
        AddOn.Active = 1
        AND product.status = 'Active'
        AND product.supplierid = 16
        AND m2mDesignation_EventProductId NOT LIKE '%-WW'
),
resv_meals (meal_resv_id, meal_prod_id, meal_stdate, meal_qty) AS (
    -- Find all meals within a reservation, we will sum them up in a later CTE
    SELECT
        reservid, product.productid, CAST(details.stdate AS date), qty
    FROM
        details JOIN product ON details.productid = product.productid 
    WHERE
        product.supplierid = 16
        AND stdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        AND dstatus NOT IN ('Cancel', 'No Show')
),
resv_events (event_resv_id, event_product_id, event_product_name, event_stdate, event_qty) AS (
    -- These are all the event products within a reservation
    SELECT
        details.reservid, product.productid, product.prodname, CAST(details.stdate AS date), SUM(qty)
    FROM details
        JOIN product ON details.productid = product.productid
        JOIN supplier ON product.supplierid = supplier.supplierid
    WHERE
        supplier.suplptype = 'Event'
        AND supplier.supplyname <> 'Adventure' -- Exclude the adventure supplier
        AND stdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        AND dstatus NOT IN ('Cancel', 'No Show')
        AND (
            -- There are 3 fares that would receive meals
            [desc] LIKE 'Adult%'
            OR [desc] LIKE 'Child%'
            OR [desc] LIKE 'Group%'
        )
        AND details.productid IN (SELECT m2m_event_id FROM event_meals)
    GROUP BY details.reservid, product.productid, product.prodname, details.stdate
    HAVING SUM(qty) < 20
),
resv_meal_sums (meal_sums_resv_id, meal_sum_event_id, meal_sums_stdate, meal_sums_qty) AS (
    -- We get a total count of the meals on each reservation. This let's us determine if they
    SELECT meal_resv_id, event_product_id, meal_stdate, SUM(meal_qty)
    FROM resv_events
        JOIN event_meals ON resv_events.event_product_id = event_meals.m2m_event_id
        JOIN resv_meals ON
            event_meals.m2m_meal_id = resv_meals.meal_prod_id
            AND resv_events.event_resv_id = resv_meals.meal_resv_id
    GROUP BY meal_resv_id, event_product_id, meal_stdate
),
meal_mismatch (resv_id, event_id, event_product_name, event_date, event_qty, missing_meal, missing_event, short_meals, excess_meals) AS (
    SELECT COALESCE(meal_sums_resv_id, event_resv_id) AS resv_id, event_product_id, event_product_name, event_stdate, event_qty,
        CASE WHEN meal_sums_qty IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS missing_meal,
        CASE WHEN event_qty IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS missing_event,
        CASE WHEN meal_sums_qty < event_qty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS short_meals,
        CASE WHEN meal_sums_qty > event_qty THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS excess_meals
    FROM resv_meal_sums
        FULL JOIN resv_events ON
            resv_meal_sums.meal_sums_resv_id = resv_events.event_resv_id
            AND meal_sum_event_id = event_product_id
            AND resv_meal_sums.meal_sums_stdate = resv_events.event_stdate
    WHERE meal_sums_qty <> event_qty OR meal_sums_qty IS NULL OR event_qty IS NULL
),
meal_pricing (meal_id, meal_date, meal_price) AS (
    SELECT avail.productid, avail.stdate, rate.unitprice
    FROM avail JOIN rate ON avail.productid = rate.productid AND avail.stdate BETWEEN rate.propfrom AND rate.propto JOIN product ON avail.productid = product.productid
    WHERE avail.stdate >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        AND avail.productid IN (SELECT m2m_meal_id FROM event_meals WHERE m2m_event_id IN (SELECT event_id FROM meal_mismatch))
        AND rate.active = 1
        AND avail.status = 1
        AND product.status = 'Active'
    GROUP BY avail.productid, avail.stdate, rate.unitprice
),
customers (resv_id, email) AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT reservid, email
    FROM meal_mismatch JOIN mmaster ON  meal_mismatch.resv_id = mmaster.reservid
    JOIN vip ON mmaster.customerid = vip.customerid
)
SELECT meal_mismatch.event_date AS [date], meal_mismatch.resv_id AS reservid,
    customers.email, event_meals.m2m_meal_name, meal_mismatch.event_qty, meal_pricing.meal_price, choice_required
FROM meal_mismatch
    JOIN customers ON meal_mismatch.resv_id = customers.resv_id AND meal_mismatch.missing_meal = 1
    JOIN event_meals ON meal_mismatch.event_id = event_meals.m2m_event_id
    JOIN meal_pricing ON event_meals.m2m_meal_id = meal_pricing.meal_id AND meal_mismatch.event_date = meal_pricing.meal_date
ORDER BY event_date, meal_mismatch.resv_id, event_id
```

My goal is to find reservations that don't have any meals, and return a result
set that has the reservation number, the number of people in the party, the
email address for the customer, the available meal options, and related pricing.

There are about 1,300 rows in the meal_mismatch and about 700 in the event_meals.

I get the results of 12,000 or so rows I expected when I left it running
after-hours. So, not a huge amount of data.

Here's the execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy0YrYwzj

Here's a sample of the result set I'm striving for:

| date | reservid | email | m2m_meal_name | event_qty | meal_price | choice_required |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-19 | 1234567 | some.customer@example.com | Something Required | 2 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 2022-12-19 | 1234567 | some.customer@example.com | At least one of these | 2 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 2022-12-19 | 1234567 | some.customer@example.com | Doesn't really matter | 2 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 2022-12-19 | 1234567 | some.customer@example.com | But these options for their particulare trip | 2 | 0.00 | 1 |
| 2022-12-19 | 7654321 | other.customer@example.com | An Option (in no particular order) | 2 | 13.00 | 0 |
| 2022-12-19 | 7654321 | other.customer@example.com | A smaller option | 2 | 8.50 | 0 |
| 2022-12-19 | 7654321 | other.customer@example.com | Another option | 2 | 13.00 | 0 |
| 2022-12-19 | 7654321 | other.customer@example.com | Yet another option | 2 | 13.00 | 0 |
| 2022-12-19 | 7654321 | other.customer@example.com | Vegetarian Option | 2 | 13.00 | 0 |

This isn't a dedicated report server and needs to run on production. How can I
speed it up?

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. `SELECT  *` will return all columns from `event_meals` so I don't see why that is necessary based on your stated goal. A column list of the needed columns from `meal_mismatch` and `customers` might help.

Comment: While in general its impossible to offer performance advice with the plan and table definitions. One common approach to speeding up complex queries such as this is to materialise the results to a temp table partway through i.e. put the results of you quick query into a temp table, then join your last table onto the temp table. SQL Server can struggle with performance if the query reaches a certain level of complexity, so by using the temp table you split the execution plan into 2, which it can sometime find easier to optimise.

Comment: Joining the same tables over and over is itself suspect. I'm guessing you could probably eliminate a lot of those joins, possibly with window functions, but it's hard to say without further details.

Comment: I've added a few more details and a bit more specific on the columns I'm looking for, and included a link to the plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Sy0YrYwzj

Comment: Does it seem odd to want the meal_name returned for reservations without any meals? [ __My goal is to find reservations that don't have any meals__ ].  I get the feeling the requirement, as stated, is incorrect.  Before worrying about performance, I tend to question the requirement, to be sure of the goal. It doesn't help to be faster and wrong.

Comment: @JonArmstrong, that is the correct requirement. I'm using the set to generate a pester message for those reservation that don't already have meals. Unfortunately, I only get one query and no other programming language to help (just some crude templating). So, the final set needs to contain all the things I need.

Comment: Maybe it's an english issue.  To me, it sounds like the following problem: "List the names of children in a family without any children."  _My goal is to find reservations that don't have any meals, and return a result set that has the reservation number, the number of people in the party, the email address for the customer, (((the meal name))), and pricing._

Comment: Maybe you're asking for the name of the meal (breakfast, lunch, dinner) for which a choice has not been specified yet.  In any case, it's tough to discuss performance when the create table statements and existing indexes are not shown... plus all the rest discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give a definite answer without looking at data / testing, but it looks like it's the IN clauses - these will run very slow if looking at a lot of data.  You can change them to EXISTS clauses to improve performance.

Change:

```
AND avail.productid IN (SELECT m2m_meal_id FROM event_meals WHERE m2m_event_id IN (SELECT event_id FROM meal_mismatch))
```

to

```
AND EXISTS (
             SELECT 1
             FROM event_meals
                 JOIN meal_mismatch ON event_meals.m2m_event_id = meal_mismatch.event_id
             WHERE avail.productid = event_meals.m2m_meal_id
         )
```

(There's a few other places with the same issue as well)